# Breaking a monolith into microservices using templates for similar apps

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, microservices

I have a huge monolith application, a ASP.NET MVC Framework service offering ~50 different "groups" of unrelated data, separated into 50 different controllers/business logics. I was tasked into breaking this monolith into 50 microservices (each one hosted in Docker containers).

What I'm planning to do is to create a "template application" using ASP.NET Core to serve as a reference project and, for each of those 50 applications, I will **fork** this "template" project, add the corresponding controller with the necessary business logic and may need or not to customize this template to add some specific features.

For example, one application may need to respond to requests using a CSV format instead of the JSON, which is the standard for ~45 apps. So, I would modify the "template project" to include this "CSV response" feature and it would be used by the other ~4 projects that would use it.

What I can see currently:

**PROS**

- Developing a ASP.NET Core application is easy, but it requires some configurations and customizations (CORS, Cache, routes, etc.) that would be already defined into "my company template" project.

**CONS**

- Forking and merging the template project can be troublesome. If we find a security issue in the template, it would be necessary to manually update all of the 50 projects and fix some potential merge conflicts.

**Is there another option available in ASP.NET Core to make this "template" project easier for updates and maintenance? Or a design pattern for this?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use a class library. Common functionality and even base controllers and such can all go there and be referenced by the actual API projects. Your common config can be added to the class library as `IServiceCollection` extensions:

```
public static class IServiceCollectionExtensions
{
    public static IServiceCollection AddMyCors(this IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddCors(...);
        return services;
    }

    ...
}
```

Then, any change to this library automatically propagates to your APIs because of the direct reference.

However, bear in mind, that pretty much the entire point of microservices is loose-coupling. You should really only share this kind of functionality for things that are relatively static and won't change. Making changes that requires every single one of 50 services to be updated, pretty much defeats the entire point.

If there's too much common, shared functionality, you have to ask yourself if you've truly decomposed the services into subdomains. A very common mistake in this way is not realizing that the actual data should be segregated as well. Ideally, each microservice should have its own data store (database, for example). If you are trying to make the microservices share the same data store, then you will inevitably end up with significant cross-over and it will be difficult if not impossible to segregate their domains. That means you loose niceties like foreign keys sometimes and you may need to even incur some data duplication. That's where CQRS, event sourcing, and other related patterns start to come into play.